# How to add composite shortcut key to activate other windows on Windows Spread mode?

Tags: 14.04, unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys, emacs

By default, pressing `super-w` will get a bunch of open windows spreaded on screen, and then we can press arrow keys to choose other inactive windows. But instead of pressing arrow key, I want to press composite key in Emacs style like `C-n C-p C-f C-b`. 
How can I do that?

[image]